# Center two UILabel together in View

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uilabel, center

Hi I want to know if i can center two uilabel together at the center as below
                     [link to image](http://postimg.org/image/tfgth575n/)

Comment: Please provide a picture of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, of course you can.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea, hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want the center line to be between the two labels.
Are you using Storyboard? If you are not using Auto Layout, then select both labels and drag them around until the center of the view controller aligns with the center of your selection (the center line will highlight).

If you are using Auto Layout, then you have to set the constraints.

1. Drag them both together until the center is at the center point between the two labels (where you want it).
2. Select one of the labels and click on the "Align" icon at the bottom right corner of the editor. Select the "Horizontal center in container" and then use the drop down arrow to set the vale to "use current canvas value". Click "Add Constraint".
3. Do this for the other label too.